# How to stop a process start by ProcessBuilder in java

Tags: java, scala

I start processes with ProcessBuilder in Java.  Multiple process may be started.  How do I stop a Process?

```
public void terminalExecute(String builder) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println(builder);
    String[] splits = builder.split(" ");
    System.out.println(splits.length);

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(splits[0],splits[1],splits[2],splits[3],splits[4],splits[5],splits[6],splits[7]);
    Process p = null ;
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true); 
    try {
        p = pb.start();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String s = "";
        while((s = in.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        int status = p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with status: " + status);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   
}
```

In another class I called this function like :

```
 String cmd ="java -Xmx3024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms1024m -cp "+ ConfReader.getAFFJarPath()+" core.StrWorkflow "+new BigInteger(serviceRequest.getBytes());
 ProcessExecutor procExec = new ProcessExecutor();
 procExec.terminalExecute(cmd);
```

How I get the process id in this class ?

Comment: add the code to show how you're starting a process in the first place and what did you try  ?

Comment: Do you got a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) Object from it? If so, you can kill it by calling the method "destroy()" on it. // EDIT: You got a Process Object from your method (Process yourProcess = terminalExecute([...])). Just call yourProcess.destroy()!

Answer (score 11):

`start()` method of `ProcessBuilder` returns a `Process` instance. You can call `destroy()` method on it.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html

Comment: `destroy()` returns error exit value. Is there any way to have the process terminated gracefully?